# Turning a list of lists into a column of arrays in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an embedding matrix - that is a list of same size embedding vectors.
Each embedding correspond to a sentence.
I have a pandas dataframe where each row represents a sentence, and I would like to add to this dataframe a new column that contains the embedding of each sentence.

I tried:

```
df['sent_emb'] = pd.DataFrame(sentences)
```

And got :

```
> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 30, placement implies 1
```

(My embedding size is 30).
I couldn't get it right without loosing the array structure.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of sentence mainly we are interested in looking at its structure.

Comment: [[ 0.00010204 -0.00025688 -0.00017324 ...,  0.00026862  0.00064974
   0.00010314]
 [ 0.00025171 -0.0004743  -0.0002827  ...,  0.00053793  0.00123609
   0.0001721 ]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can pass the sentences as `pandas series`. Below is a minimal example for understanding:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'aaa': ['a','b','c']})
ex = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],4,5,6]
df['sentences'] = pd.Series(ex)
print(df)

    aaa sentences
0   a   [1, 2, 3]
1   b   [2, 3, 4]
2   c       4
```

Comment: It is strange, but with np array this does not work!!! should convert to list first!

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a `pd.DataFrame` to a `pd.Series`, that can't work.

Maybe try tris :

```
df['sent_emb'] = sentences
```

Comment: Tried and still get the same error: Wrong number of items passed 30, placement implies 1